# await User.findOne({email}); returns fail

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mern, react-fullstack

I am trying to create a login authentication for my form. I have created the user with a hashed password using bcrypt, I am trying to log in but it keeps returning failed. The email and password are both correct I have double checked. This is my server-side code:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const User = require("./models/user.js");


require("dotenv").config();
const app = express();
const bcryptSalt= bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors({
    credentials: true,
    origin: "http://localhost:5173",
}));

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL);


app.get("/test",(req,res) => {
    res.json("test ok");
});

app.post("/register",async (req,res) => {
    const{name, email, password} = req.body;
  
    try{
        const newUser = await User.create ({
            name,
            email,
            password: bcrypt.hashSync(password, bcryptSalt)
        });
        res.json(newUser);
    
    } catch (e){
        res.status(422).json(e);
    }
});

app.post("/login", async (req,res) => {
    const {email, password} = req.body;
    const newUser = await User.findOne({email});
    if (newUser){

       const passOk= bcrypt.compareSync(password, newUser.password);
       if (passOk) {
        res.json("pass ok");
       } else{
        res.status(422).json("pass not ok");
       }

    } else {
        res.json("not found");
    }

});

  

app.listen(4000);
```

I have checked the server logs for any errors that might be preventing the login process from working correctly. There were no error messages instead I keep getting the "login failed" alert whenever I try to log in. Here is my client-side code:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import {useState} from "react"
;
function LoginPage () {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
    const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

    async function handleOnSubmit (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        try{
            await axios.post("/login", {email, password});
            alert("login successful");
        } catch (e) {
            alert("login failed");
        }
        

    }

    return (
        <div className="mt-4 grow flex items-center justify-around">
        <div className="mb-64">
        <h1 className="text-4xl text-center mb-4">Login</h1>
            <form className="max-w-md mx-auto" onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}>
                <input type="email" 
                placeholder="your@email.com" 
                value={email} 
                onChange={ev => setEmail(ev.target.value)} />
                <input type="password"
                 placeholder="password"
                 value={password} 
                 onChange={ev => setPassword(ev.target.value)} />
                <button className="primary">Login</button>
                <div className="text-center py-2 text-gray-500">
                    Don't have an account yet? <Link className="underline text-black" to={"/register"}>Register now</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    )

}
export default LoginPage;
```

Comment: You get "login failed" because `axios.post` threw an exception.  Which exception did it throw?  What are the details of that exception?

Comment: The first thing is to check what error you have in your `catch` block. With that error you can figure out what the reason is or where you need to continue searching.

Comment: Also, `res.json("some string")` is not a valid JSON.

Comment: @PrerakSola Sure it is. "*The parameter can be any JSON type, including object, array, string, Boolean, number, or null*" - https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json.

Comment: What does `console.log('passOk:', passOk)` logs?

Comment: Thanks @Wyck this worked for me, axios was not defined in the login page.

Comment: @PrerakSola, The argument to `res.json` **becomes** JSON (is encoded in JSON format, which is then transmitted in the body of the response).  The implementation passes the argument to `JSON.stringify` to do the encoding.  And it's totally fine because `JSON.stringify("some string") === '"some string"'`.  See [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for details.